# How to compare hexadecimal value using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

How to compare hexadecimal value using powershell ?

```
22
32
44
56
de
4f
3f
```

These values are in a file and I need to compare them to find the largest value amongst them. These are hex values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way:

```
$n = 22,32,44,56,"de","4f","3f" # or $n = get-content myfilewithHEX.txt 
[Convert]::ToString( ($n | % { [int]"0x$_" } | Measure-Object -Maximum).maximum , 16)
```

this returns `de`

another way:

```
 ( $n | sort { [int]"0x$_" } ) | select -Last 1
```

Comment: thanks alot , this works great :), I like the second way , lot less to type

Comment: @Frown Me too :) Glad to help!